# Show that there are no solutions to $x^2 + y^2 = 3z^2$ in $\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm attempting to work through some of the questions in Whitelaw's "Introduction to Abstract Algebra" but am having some difficulty.

The question is as follows

> Show that $\forall n \in \Bbb{Z},$ $n^2 \equiv 0\  \text{or}\  1 \mod{3}.$ Show further that $$3\rvert(x^2 + y^2) \implies 3\rvert x\ \text{and}\ 3\rvert y.$$
>   Deduce that there is no solution in $\Bbb{Z}$ to the equation
>   $$x^2 + y^2 = 3z^2$$ 
>   except $x = y = z = 0.$

For the first part, I simply let $n = 3k,$ $3k+1$ or $3k + 2$ with $k \in \Bbb{Z}$. Hence,

\begin{align}
(3k)^2 &\equiv 0 \mod{3}\\
(3k+1)^2 = 9k^2 + 6k + 1 &\equiv 1\mod{3}\\
(3k+2)^2 = 9k^2 + 12k + 3 + 1 &\equiv 1\mod{3}.
\end{align}

For the second part, since $n^2 \equiv 0$ or $1 \mod{3}$, and that the only case in which $n^2 \equiv 0 \mod{3}$ was when $3\rvert n$, it must then be the case that both $x^2$ and $y^2$ are divisible by $3$ for $3$ to divide their sum (else we get that $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 1$ or $2 \mod{3}$). We also know that if $3\rvert n$ then $3\rvert n^2$. Hence, $3\rvert x$ and $3\rvert y$.

I am, however, unsure how to approach the third part.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Comment on the proof on the second part: If $3|n$ then $3|n^2$, but you want the converse of that statement. The only way that $3|(x^2+y^2)$ is if $x^2$ and $y^2$ are both $\equiv 0 \mod 3$. Now, use (from what you computed) that $n^2\equiv 0 \mod 3$ if and only if $n\equiv 0 \mod 3$. The idea was correct, but reorganizing might make it a touch clearer.

Comment: Your very last sentence doesn't follow.  If 3|n then 3|n^2, yes, but the converse doesn't follow.(9|36 but 9 doesn't divide 6)  Here we need to state that 3 is prime and if 3|n^2 then 3|n.  And that should give you a hint to the second part.  Everything up to that last sentence was perfect.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help. I will amend this in my notes!

Comment: x^2 + y^2 = 0 mod 3 only if both x and y are divisible by 3 as x^2 and y^2 can only be = 0,1 (not -1) mod 3.  So if x^2 + y^2=3z^2 then 3 divides x and y.  So 9 divides x^2 +y^2 so 3 divides z^2 so 9 divides z^2.  so 27 divides x^2 and y^2 and so on ad infinitim.

Comment: @fleablood, I forgot to add that $3$ is prime, which is a more elegant way of using $3|n^2|$ to establish that $3|n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose that we have a solution $(a,b,c)$ where $c\neq 0$ is the smallest positive integer such that the equality holds.

$$a^2 + b^2= 3c^2 \Rightarrow 3|(a^2 + b^2)$$

But we know that this means $3|a$ and $3|b$. However, on squaring we get that $9$ divides the LHS, and so it must also divide the RHS:
$$a'^2 + b'^2 = \frac{c^2}{3}$$

Where $3a' = a, 3b' = b$. But $3$ is prime, so if it divides the product it must divide $c$. Factor that out as $3c'$ and divide:
$$a'^2 + b'^2 = 3c'^2$$

But this is another solution triple with $c' < c$ (and also $c' \neq 0$), and we chose the smallest possible $c$, so we have a contradiction.